# Scheme over a DVR

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a discrete valuation ring with finite residue field $k$ of characteristic $p$.

Let $S=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ be a noetherian scheme over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O})$. Are there sufficient conditions on $S[1/p]$ and $S \mod p$ so that $S$ is irreducible ?

Answer (score 2):

For the notation $S[1/p]$ to make sense, you have to suppose $\mathcal O$ has characteristic $0$.

1. If $S$ is irreducible, then $S[1/p]$, being an open subset of $S$, is also irreducible. But $S_p$ ($S$ mod $p$) can be essentially anything.
2. If $S[1/p]$ is irreducible and $S$ is flat over $\mathcal O$ (meaning that $R$ has no torsion over $\mathcal O$: $ar=0$ with $a\in \mathcal O$ and $r\in R$ implies that $a=0$ or $r=0$), then $S$ itself is irreducible because the flatness implies that $S[1/p]$ is dense in $S$.
3. Without flatness, you can add any hypothesis you want on $S_p$ (plus the irreducibility of $S[1/p]$), you can't guarantee that $S$ is irreducible: take the union of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal O)$ with any scheme $T$ over $\mathcal O/p\mathcal O$ of positive dimension and make them meet at one point of $T$ (this imposes that $T$ has a rational point, but this is not a strong constraint), the resulting scheme is connected with irreducible fibers, but is not irreducible.

Comment: Why does flatness imply that  $S[1/p]$ is dense in $S$ ?

Comment: Because flat base change preserves scheme theoretic image in this case so it is just by the definition of flatness.